# Change the default directory for Brackets

Tags: adobe-brackets

I have tons of files in my home directory (`~`), and each time I open Brackets, it tries to load and index all the files there. Eventually, after freezing for a minute, it throws the error:

```
Error Indexing Files: The maximum number of files have been indexed.
```

I can of course switch directories after this freeze, but how do I set the default directory for Brackets to be another directory (not the home directory), thus avoiding this freeze each time Brackets is initiated?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Brackets should be remembering whichever project you had open last. Your state settings file may be corrupt. Try these steps:

1. Quit Brackets
2. Navigate to the following folder:

   - Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/Brackets`
   - Linux: `~/.config/brackets`
3. Find the `state.json` file and change the `projectPath` parameter to a new default path
4. If `state.json` cannot be found, make sure this folder has write permissions for your user account

If the above did not work, try opening the `state.json` to see if it's corrupted (possibly by a buggy extension). If all fails delete the file altogether and restart.

Comment: This got me on the right tracks thank you! I had to change the parameter `projectPath` to another path that's not my home directory. I still throws the error but no longer freezes on initiation!