# Brackets on Windows 7: How to set the default directory for file open/save?

Tags: windows-7-x64, savefiledialog, adobe-brackets

While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29212969/change-the-default-directory-for-brackets) may have a correct answer for other OSes, it doesn't work for Windows 7.

The problem is that [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) doesn't remember the last used directory and the file open/save dialog is constantly shown with the localized version of "Getting started" example.

How to reproduce:

- Use Windows 7.
- Create a new empty file within Brackets.
- Save as.

[image]
<sup>(French version)</sup>

I was not able to find in the registry any default path (the last position of the editor window is stored in the registry), nor the `state.json` configuration file mentioned in the other question answer.

Looking at the documentation for [showSaveDialog()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29212969/change-the-default-directory-for-brackets):

> **initialPath string**
>
> The folder opened inside the window initially. If initialPath is not
>   set, or it doesn't exist, the window would show the last browsed
>   folder depending on the OS preferences.

I don't understand the meaning of "depending on the OS preferences" either.

There are bugs in various status related to this problem, but they don't seem to be about to be solved:

- "Open/Save/Save as" directory defaults do Brackets folder [#8576](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/8576)
- Save location always set to "Getting Started". Can't use my last save Folder [#11181](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/11181).